# Typescript and Subpath Imports

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to get Node subpath imports and typescript to work.  My IDE has no problem resolving the imports, but Typescript is never happy.

Github repo with code: https://github.com/doronrosenberg/ts-subpath-imports.

package.json:

```
  "imports": {
    "#internal/*": "./internal/*.ts",
    "#internal2": "./internal"
  }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
  "paths": {
    "#internal/*": "./internal/*.ts",
    "#internal2": ["./internal"]
  }
```

and the code:

```
import { foo } from "#internal/index";
import { bar } from "#internal2";
```

No matter how I set things up, I always get:

```
src/test.ts:1:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '#internal/index' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { foo } from "#internal/index";
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/test.ts:2:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '#internal2' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { bar } from "#internal2";
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't look too promising looking up issues and people who have picked it up and dropped it. I'll be following the thread for answers, "imports" sounds cool.

Answer (score 12):

After hacking around with Typescript for a few weeks, I got a working solution.

Let's say I have a package called `@kodadot1/metasquid` with multiple submodules (`consolidator` and `entity`).

In my `package.json` I declare `imports`

```json
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/index.cjs"
    },
    "./consolidator": {
      "types": "./dist/consolidator.d.ts",
      "import": "./dist/consolidator.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/consolidator.cjs"
    },
    "./entity": {
      "types": "./dist/entity.d.ts",
      "import": "./dist/entity.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/entity.cjs"
    }
}
```

The trick is to create a `.d.ts` file for each submodule in the project's root.

So for submodule `entity` I will make a file called `entity.d.ts` that contains

```
export * from './dist/entity'
```

Now to publish it correctly in [npmjs](https://npmjs.com) extend your `package.json` like:

```json
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "*.d.ts"
  ]
```

Now just publish, and you can enjoy subpath imports:

```
import { get } from '@kodadot1/metasquid/entity'
```

[Whole code is available here](https://github.com/kodadot/packages/tree/main/metasquid)

Comment: Have a very similar issue. Can you spot the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76236503/200987

Comment: Do you assume that `dist` folder already exists and contains the desired file ? Because if you try to export something that doesn't exist (e.g `export * from './dist/myEntity';`) it will throw `Cannot find module './dist/myEntity' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`.  In my case `dist` folder is created when calling `rollup` to bundle my packages, so is not always available .  This kind of error is thrown due a wrong Typescript config ?

Answer (score 6):

The support of subpath exports requires newer module resolutions such as `Node16` and `NodeNext`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "Node16" // or `"NodeNext"`
  }
}
```

Comment: This one did the trick for me. It should be noted that module resolution must be set in the project that imports the package, not in the package itself.

Comment: but then that fcks up imports from a lot of other packages ,unfortunately

Comment: @spock, yes. But that’s the problem of overall ESM adaptation. We still have a long way to go.